# Where, Exactly, can the Works Searched for by This Exchange be Found?

Tags: discussion, story-identification

There's a constant stream of story identification threads, and inevitably answers appear with paragraphs from the text to verify the story that's been looked for. Yet, when I click the link to the ISFDB page, the only publication is a magazine in 1982 and there doesn't seem to be any link to a scan/transcription of said physical media. I'd love a chance to read some of these myself...

So the question is, *where exactly are all of these found*?

Comment: You're going to need to be a lot more specific than this.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get "more specific" than this. Perhaps "what resources do people use to find full transcripts of stories that were only published in print, once, 40 years ago?"

Comment: When one's job involves flying a keyboard most of most days, it's a bit of a chore, but not exceptionally slow, to transcribe text from a page.  Though I have to admit I sometimes wish for one of those stands that would (gently) hold a book open for you, without having to use a stack of other books...

Comment: @DavidW - ABBYY Finereader is your friend. It will handily transcribe a screenshot or a photograph of a page of text. Alternatively, you can always read the relevant passage to a voice-to-text app like speechtexter or MSWord Speech.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A lot of us find copies of the old magazines on archive.org, books.google.com, or random sites on the internet once we have a phrase to go off of (although, of course, we try to avoid posting links to copyright-infringing sites, although excerpted quotes are pretty OK). And, in some cases, people are transcribing from the paper copies they own. Oh, and Gutenberg.org is good for items in the public domain.

Comment: If possible I scan and OCR it. But if not possible, I find it a lot easier to find stuff in the Luminist Archive than the Internet archive. http://www.luminist.org/archives/SF/title_index.htm